# How to put an svg path with a viewbox inside another svg data with another viewbox

Tags: html, typescript, svg

I have this svg element image of a bass cleff:

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="36.16 204.35 284.921 811.583" width="284.921" height="811.583">
      <path d="m200.680145,652.121826c-12.46701,2.556702 -24.020721,9.3974 -35.04837,20.294373c-11.041428,11.096924 -16.951889,23.753906 -17.918106,37.757019c-0.607315,8.802002 1.710495,19.011719 6.794357,30.015381c5.070023,11.203613 13.355072,19.614136 24.440247,25.403992c3.754883,1.063049 5.421631,3.187988 5.228394,5.988647c-0.069,1.000244 -1.541763,1.903564 -5.005981,2.468567c-17.930832,-5.860168 -32.294312,-16.700073 -42.91748,-32.105835c-10.609375,-15.605835 -15.465866,-32.824646 -14.541847,-52.05658c2.023293,-20.563049 9.564827,-39.33844 22.610786,-56.125977c13.2603,-16.973816 29.57074,-28.511169 48.931351,-34.612183l-8.9366,-71.97052c-32.648514,23.474854 -59.550636,48.351257 -80.934525,75.01532c-21.370087,26.46405 -33.480858,55.978943 -36.532852,88.530884c-0.606544,14.63092 1.42141,29.041626 6.097679,43.032043c4.66246,14.190491 12.228981,27.174377 22.671944,39.351807c21.10025,24.168518 49.763901,38.005066 85.576111,41.682068c12.287582,0.043823 25.473907,-1.257263 39.759521,-3.889526l-20.274628,-158.77948zm14.576233,-1.004211l20.668411,155.992676c31.737534,-10.271912 49.041763,-36.212524 51.885178,-77.421692c-0.852386,-13.927612 -4.007233,-26.607117 -10.066132,-38.080017c-5.844543,-11.659058 -14.060577,-21.069824 -24.848618,-28.246094c-10.788025,-7.17627 -23.200623,-11.248657 -37.63884,-12.244873zm-26.75383,-210.882782c6.89357,-3.544281 14.996841,-10.02005 23.894958,-19.254913c8.884293,-9.034882 17.692276,-19.883942 26.195831,-32.161011c8.717896,-12.463287 15.845337,-25.237274 21.382339,-38.322021c5.523193,-12.884705 8.598633,-25.335297 9.39917,-36.937866c0.345093,-5.001129 0.289093,-10.029907 -0.409882,-14.500061c-0.305237,-7.256958 -2.124603,-13.010376 -5.672424,-17.074127c-3.561646,-3.863708 -8.236328,-6.196228 -14.252258,-6.611328c-12.03186,-0.83017 -23.371216,5.82431 -34.018097,19.96344c-8.30304,12.290924 -15.568512,27.065369 -21.167236,43.964783c-5.813049,17.085632 -9.606995,34.109589 -11.208908,51.485779c-0.363815,19.873596 1.726639,36.298584 5.856506,49.447327zm-13.434006,10.730896c-6.787811,-33.029846 -9.523605,-66.383118 -8.207397,-100.059753c1.691254,-21.590942 5.291183,-41.64325 10.799805,-60.156891c5.308075,-18.527435 12.241516,-34.329803 20.827866,-47.807098c8.385849,-13.49118 17.740219,-23.498566 27.86261,-30.036041c9.064499,-5.806458 15.51561,-8.77829 18.924652,-8.54306c2.606888,0.179871 4.743713,1.332306 6.624786,3.271057c1.881088,1.938782 4.28096,5.119324 7.213394,9.341583c21.530457,35.454071 30.746521,77.093323 27.461456,124.703888c-1.559723,22.605042 -6.085999,44.402405 -13.620239,65.992188c-7.319916,21.403595 -17.378235,41.613251 -30.147369,60.228882c-12.983459,18.80188 -27.792801,34.864777 -44.642349,48.374969l10.804672,79.938293c8.892365,-0.391479 14.963501,-0.77655 18.372528,-0.541321c15.240341,1.051575 28.655579,5.193176 40.847321,12.466309c12.191742,7.273132 22.42691,16.622192 30.491089,28.233398c8.078003,11.411255 14.040283,24.284424 17.88681,38.619629c3.646027,14.32135 5.2453,29.104492 4.196289,44.307861c-1.628723,23.605225 -9.335907,44.781128 -23.107697,63.327576c-13.77179,18.546448 -33.401154,31.46283 -59.102432,38.935303c0.927917,9.912903 2.755341,24.309753 5.710419,42.804382c2.740738,18.680847 4.741104,33.491638 6.001068,44.432373c1.259949,10.940735 1.344315,21.398438 0.640366,31.600708c-1.090424,15.803589 -5.866699,29.543701 -14.342651,41.420654c-8.676483,11.863159 -19.766617,20.745789 -33.470932,26.634094c-13.503815,5.902161 -28.176682,8.306641 -43.818085,7.227417c-22.05838,-1.521973 -40.881439,-9.051636 -56.483002,-22.388916c-15.587738,-13.537292 -23.265457,-30.749817 -22.604477,-52.01001c1.25032,-9.360474 4.063484,-18.010254 8.653831,-26.135376c4.59034,-8.125122 10.473953,-14.553101 17.851418,-19.269958c7.19072,-4.930786 15.605728,-7.164124 25.072083,-7.113892c7.820694,0.539612 15.088501,3.252014 21.817215,7.937317c6.514374,4.871399 11.728973,11.060059 15.429413,18.752258c3.499893,7.678406 5.139816,16.03241 4.532501,24.834351c-0.814377,11.802673 -5.515121,21.528076 -14.10228,29.176453c-8.587143,7.648376 -19.10408,11.143738 -31.336456,10.299622l-4.612206,-0.318176c6.992531,12.542297 19.398598,19.629211 37.245842,20.860657c9.02388,0.622559 18.386337,-0.741333 27.859207,-3.705688c9.687195,-3.150513 17.852966,-7.612061 24.91217,-13.556885c7.059219,-5.944885 11.940186,-12.441956 14.241852,-19.518982c3.97496,-7.966553 6.365967,-19.258423 7.345963,-33.461609c0.662552,-9.602112 0.322418,-19.273376 -0.819809,-29.000061c-1.156052,-9.526611 -3.093903,-22.32312 -5.827362,-38.189514c-2.747253,-15.666321 -4.726517,-27.862732 -5.764832,-36.175232c-12.238907,2.170471 -24.782227,2.913025 -37.816742,2.013611c-21.857834,-1.508118 -42.208862,-7.33429 -61.039207,-17.678406c-18.83036,-10.344116 -35.019707,-23.923035 -48.754761,-40.950439c-13.534512,-17.013611 -23.722504,-35.806335 -30.536373,-56.778137c-6.62714,-20.757996 -9.375191,-42.253235 -8.057411,-64.271973c2.210022,-20.349182 7.372784,-39.690674 15.861763,-57.59668c8.502769,-18.106018 18.941837,-35.073425 31.503925,-50.688416c12.562096,-15.61499 25.428627,-29.801971 38.585793,-42.360931c13.343895,-12.345093 30.760139,-28.228119 52.635963,-47.421387z" id="path9" stroke-width="0.602291" stroke="#131516" fill-rule="evenodd" style=""/>
    </svg>
```

I want to put this data inside musical notation, which is another svg element built from midi data, that contains other notes lines etc, which has it's own viewBox.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 320 3200">
</svg>
```

How to I adjust the bass cleff size to fit into this new svg? I thought about dividing the numbers inside path data to adjust for the new svg viewBox, is there a better way?

I tried to use a symbol as described here: https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/,
Here's my product:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 5760 320">
  <symbol viewBox="36.16 204.35 284.921 811.583">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="811" height="284" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="red"></rect>
  </symbol>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="5760" y2="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="120" x2="5760" y2="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="160" x2="5760" y2="160" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="5760" y2="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="240" x2="5760" y2="240" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <use href="#gclef" fill="red"></use>
</svg>
```

I've replaced contents of the symbol #gclef with a red rectangle for debugging,
But the use doesn't render the rectangle.

If I put in path data and render a g clef, it renders, but I can't position it properly.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the music notation svg target? Appending the bass cleff to another svg should be pretty easy.  The tricky part is to place the clef element appropriately without overlapping notes in the target svg.

Comment: Change the inner <svg> tag to a <symbol> and use it with a <use>. Since the symbol has a viewBox the use element can take a width and a height, Also you can position ti as needed with a x and a y attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed one `<svg>` element as a child of another `<svg>`. The `viewBox` will work.  You can use the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` attributes to size and position it.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 5760 320">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="5760" y2="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="120" x2="5760" y2="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="160" x2="5760" y2="160" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="5760" y2="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="240" x2="5760" y2="240" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  
  <svg viewBox="36.16 204.35 284.921 811.583" width="100" x="20">
    <path d="m200.680145,652.121826c-12.46701,2.556702 -24.020721,9.3974 -35.04837,20.294373c-11.041428,11.096924 -16.951889,23.753906 -17.918106,37.757019c-0.607315,8.802002 1.710495,19.011719 6.794357,30.015381c5.070023,11.203613 13.355072,19.614136 24.440247,25.403992c3.754883,1.063049 5.421631,3.187988 5.228394,5.988647c-0.069,1.000244 -1.541763,1.903564 -5.005981,2.468567c-17.930832,-5.860168 -32.294312,-16.700073 -42.91748,-32.105835c-10.609375,-15.605835 -15.465866,-32.824646 -14.541847,-52.05658c2.023293,-20.563049 9.564827,-39.33844 22.610786,-56.125977c13.2603,-16.973816 29.57074,-28.511169 48.931351,-34.612183l-8.9366,-71.97052c-32.648514,23.474854 -59.550636,48.351257 -80.934525,75.01532c-21.370087,26.46405 -33.480858,55.978943 -36.532852,88.530884c-0.606544,14.63092 1.42141,29.041626 6.097679,43.032043c4.66246,14.190491 12.228981,27.174377 22.671944,39.351807c21.10025,24.168518 49.763901,38.005066 85.576111,41.682068c12.287582,0.043823 25.473907,-1.257263 39.759521,-3.889526l-20.274628,-158.77948zm14.576233,-1.004211l20.668411,155.992676c31.737534,-10.271912 49.041763,-36.212524 51.885178,-77.421692c-0.852386,-13.927612 -4.007233,-26.607117 -10.066132,-38.080017c-5.844543,-11.659058 -14.060577,-21.069824 -24.848618,-28.246094c-10.788025,-7.17627 -23.200623,-11.248657 -37.63884,-12.244873zm-26.75383,-210.882782c6.89357,-3.544281 14.996841,-10.02005 23.894958,-19.254913c8.884293,-9.034882 17.692276,-19.883942 26.195831,-32.161011c8.717896,-12.463287 15.845337,-25.237274 21.382339,-38.322021c5.523193,-12.884705 8.598633,-25.335297 9.39917,-36.937866c0.345093,-5.001129 0.289093,-10.029907 -0.409882,-14.500061c-0.305237,-7.256958 -2.124603,-13.010376 -5.672424,-17.074127c-3.561646,-3.863708 -8.236328,-6.196228 -14.252258,-6.611328c-12.03186,-0.83017 -23.371216,5.82431 -34.018097,19.96344c-8.30304,12.290924 -15.568512,27.065369 -21.167236,43.964783c-5.813049,17.085632 -9.606995,34.109589 -11.208908,51.485779c-0.363815,19.873596 1.726639,36.298584 5.856506,49.447327zm-13.434006,10.730896c-6.787811,-33.029846 -9.523605,-66.383118 -8.207397,-100.059753c1.691254,-21.590942 5.291183,-41.64325 10.799805,-60.156891c5.308075,-18.527435 12.241516,-34.329803 20.827866,-47.807098c8.385849,-13.49118 17.740219,-23.498566 27.86261,-30.036041c9.064499,-5.806458 15.51561,-8.77829 18.924652,-8.54306c2.606888,0.179871 4.743713,1.332306 6.624786,3.271057c1.881088,1.938782 4.28096,5.119324 7.213394,9.341583c21.530457,35.454071 30.746521,77.093323 27.461456,124.703888c-1.559723,22.605042 -6.085999,44.402405 -13.620239,65.992188c-7.319916,21.403595 -17.378235,41.613251 -30.147369,60.228882c-12.983459,18.80188 -27.792801,34.864777 -44.642349,48.374969l10.804672,79.938293c8.892365,-0.391479 14.963501,-0.77655 18.372528,-0.541321c15.240341,1.051575 28.655579,5.193176 40.847321,12.466309c12.191742,7.273132 22.42691,16.622192 30.491089,28.233398c8.078003,11.411255 14.040283,24.284424 17.88681,38.619629c3.646027,14.32135 5.2453,29.104492 4.196289,44.307861c-1.628723,23.605225 -9.335907,44.781128 -23.107697,63.327576c-13.77179,18.546448 -33.401154,31.46283 -59.102432,38.935303c0.927917,9.912903 2.755341,24.309753 5.710419,42.804382c2.740738,18.680847 4.741104,33.491638 6.001068,44.432373c1.259949,10.940735 1.344315,21.398438 0.640366,31.600708c-1.090424,15.803589 -5.866699,29.543701 -14.342651,41.420654c-8.676483,11.863159 -19.766617,20.745789 -33.470932,26.634094c-13.503815,5.902161 -28.176682,8.306641 -43.818085,7.227417c-22.05838,-1.521973 -40.881439,-9.051636 -56.483002,-22.388916c-15.587738,-13.537292 -23.265457,-30.749817 -22.604477,-52.01001c1.25032,-9.360474 4.063484,-18.010254 8.653831,-26.135376c4.59034,-8.125122 10.473953,-14.553101 17.851418,-19.269958c7.19072,-4.930786 15.605728,-7.164124 25.072083,-7.113892c7.820694,0.539612 15.088501,3.252014 21.817215,7.937317c6.514374,4.871399 11.728973,11.060059 15.429413,18.752258c3.499893,7.678406 5.139816,16.03241 4.532501,24.834351c-0.814377,11.802673 -5.515121,21.528076 -14.10228,29.176453c-8.587143,7.648376 -19.10408,11.143738 -31.336456,10.299622l-4.612206,-0.318176c6.992531,12.542297 19.398598,19.629211 37.245842,20.860657c9.02388,0.622559 18.386337,-0.741333 27.859207,-3.705688c9.687195,-3.150513 17.852966,-7.612061 24.91217,-13.556885c7.059219,-5.944885 11.940186,-12.441956 14.241852,-19.518982c3.97496,-7.966553 6.365967,-19.258423 7.345963,-33.461609c0.662552,-9.602112 0.322418,-19.273376 -0.819809,-29.000061c-1.156052,-9.526611 -3.093903,-22.32312 -5.827362,-38.189514c-2.747253,-15.666321 -4.726517,-27.862732 -5.764832,-36.175232c-12.238907,2.170471 -24.782227,2.913025 -37.816742,2.013611c-21.857834,-1.508118 -42.208862,-7.33429 -61.039207,-17.678406c-18.83036,-10.344116 -35.019707,-23.923035 -48.754761,-40.950439c-13.534512,-17.013611 -23.722504,-35.806335 -30.536373,-56.778137c-6.62714,-20.757996 -9.375191,-42.253235 -8.057411,-64.271973c2.210022,-20.349182 7.372784,-39.690674 15.861763,-57.59668c8.502769,-18.106018 18.941837,-35.073425 31.503925,-50.688416c12.562096,-15.61499 25.428627,-29.801971 38.585793,-42.360931c13.343895,-12.345093 30.760139,-28.228119 52.635963,-47.421387z" id="path9" stroke-width="0.602291" stroke="#131516" fill-rule="evenodd" style=""/>
  </svg>

</svg>
```

Or you can turn the clef into a `<symbol>`, and use it that way.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" viewBox="0 0 5760 320">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="gclef" viewBox="36.16 204.35 284.921 811.583">
      <path d="m200.680145,652.121826c-12.46701,2.556702 -24.020721,9.3974 -35.04837,20.294373c-11.041428,11.096924 -16.951889,23.753906 -17.918106,37.757019c-0.607315,8.802002 1.710495,19.011719 6.794357,30.015381c5.070023,11.203613 13.355072,19.614136 24.440247,25.403992c3.754883,1.063049 5.421631,3.187988 5.228394,5.988647c-0.069,1.000244 -1.541763,1.903564 -5.005981,2.468567c-17.930832,-5.860168 -32.294312,-16.700073 -42.91748,-32.105835c-10.609375,-15.605835 -15.465866,-32.824646 -14.541847,-52.05658c2.023293,-20.563049 9.564827,-39.33844 22.610786,-56.125977c13.2603,-16.973816 29.57074,-28.511169 48.931351,-34.612183l-8.9366,-71.97052c-32.648514,23.474854 -59.550636,48.351257 -80.934525,75.01532c-21.370087,26.46405 -33.480858,55.978943 -36.532852,88.530884c-0.606544,14.63092 1.42141,29.041626 6.097679,43.032043c4.66246,14.190491 12.228981,27.174377 22.671944,39.351807c21.10025,24.168518 49.763901,38.005066 85.576111,41.682068c12.287582,0.043823 25.473907,-1.257263 39.759521,-3.889526l-20.274628,-158.77948zm14.576233,-1.004211l20.668411,155.992676c31.737534,-10.271912 49.041763,-36.212524 51.885178,-77.421692c-0.852386,-13.927612 -4.007233,-26.607117 -10.066132,-38.080017c-5.844543,-11.659058 -14.060577,-21.069824 -24.848618,-28.246094c-10.788025,-7.17627 -23.200623,-11.248657 -37.63884,-12.244873zm-26.75383,-210.882782c6.89357,-3.544281 14.996841,-10.02005 23.894958,-19.254913c8.884293,-9.034882 17.692276,-19.883942 26.195831,-32.161011c8.717896,-12.463287 15.845337,-25.237274 21.382339,-38.322021c5.523193,-12.884705 8.598633,-25.335297 9.39917,-36.937866c0.345093,-5.001129 0.289093,-10.029907 -0.409882,-14.500061c-0.305237,-7.256958 -2.124603,-13.010376 -5.672424,-17.074127c-3.561646,-3.863708 -8.236328,-6.196228 -14.252258,-6.611328c-12.03186,-0.83017 -23.371216,5.82431 -34.018097,19.96344c-8.30304,12.290924 -15.568512,27.065369 -21.167236,43.964783c-5.813049,17.085632 -9.606995,34.109589 -11.208908,51.485779c-0.363815,19.873596 1.726639,36.298584 5.856506,49.447327zm-13.434006,10.730896c-6.787811,-33.029846 -9.523605,-66.383118 -8.207397,-100.059753c1.691254,-21.590942 5.291183,-41.64325 10.799805,-60.156891c5.308075,-18.527435 12.241516,-34.329803 20.827866,-47.807098c8.385849,-13.49118 17.740219,-23.498566 27.86261,-30.036041c9.064499,-5.806458 15.51561,-8.77829 18.924652,-8.54306c2.606888,0.179871 4.743713,1.332306 6.624786,3.271057c1.881088,1.938782 4.28096,5.119324 7.213394,9.341583c21.530457,35.454071 30.746521,77.093323 27.461456,124.703888c-1.559723,22.605042 -6.085999,44.402405 -13.620239,65.992188c-7.319916,21.403595 -17.378235,41.613251 -30.147369,60.228882c-12.983459,18.80188 -27.792801,34.864777 -44.642349,48.374969l10.804672,79.938293c8.892365,-0.391479 14.963501,-0.77655 18.372528,-0.541321c15.240341,1.051575 28.655579,5.193176 40.847321,12.466309c12.191742,7.273132 22.42691,16.622192 30.491089,28.233398c8.078003,11.411255 14.040283,24.284424 17.88681,38.619629c3.646027,14.32135 5.2453,29.104492 4.196289,44.307861c-1.628723,23.605225 -9.335907,44.781128 -23.107697,63.327576c-13.77179,18.546448 -33.401154,31.46283 -59.102432,38.935303c0.927917,9.912903 2.755341,24.309753 5.710419,42.804382c2.740738,18.680847 4.741104,33.491638 6.001068,44.432373c1.259949,10.940735 1.344315,21.398438 0.640366,31.600708c-1.090424,15.803589 -5.866699,29.543701 -14.342651,41.420654c-8.676483,11.863159 -19.766617,20.745789 -33.470932,26.634094c-13.503815,5.902161 -28.176682,8.306641 -43.818085,7.227417c-22.05838,-1.521973 -40.881439,-9.051636 -56.483002,-22.388916c-15.587738,-13.537292 -23.265457,-30.749817 -22.604477,-52.01001c1.25032,-9.360474 4.063484,-18.010254 8.653831,-26.135376c4.59034,-8.125122 10.473953,-14.553101 17.851418,-19.269958c7.19072,-4.930786 15.605728,-7.164124 25.072083,-7.113892c7.820694,0.539612 15.088501,3.252014 21.817215,7.937317c6.514374,4.871399 11.728973,11.060059 15.429413,18.752258c3.499893,7.678406 5.139816,16.03241 4.532501,24.834351c-0.814377,11.802673 -5.515121,21.528076 -14.10228,29.176453c-8.587143,7.648376 -19.10408,11.143738 -31.336456,10.299622l-4.612206,-0.318176c6.992531,12.542297 19.398598,19.629211 37.245842,20.860657c9.02388,0.622559 18.386337,-0.741333 27.859207,-3.705688c9.687195,-3.150513 17.852966,-7.612061 24.91217,-13.556885c7.059219,-5.944885 11.940186,-12.441956 14.241852,-19.518982c3.97496,-7.966553 6.365967,-19.258423 7.345963,-33.461609c0.662552,-9.602112 0.322418,-19.273376 -0.819809,-29.000061c-1.156052,-9.526611 -3.093903,-22.32312 -5.827362,-38.189514c-2.747253,-15.666321 -4.726517,-27.862732 -5.764832,-36.175232c-12.238907,2.170471 -24.782227,2.913025 -37.816742,2.013611c-21.857834,-1.508118 -42.208862,-7.33429 -61.039207,-17.678406c-18.83036,-10.344116 -35.019707,-23.923035 -48.754761,-40.950439c-13.534512,-17.013611 -23.722504,-35.806335 -30.536373,-56.778137c-6.62714,-20.757996 -9.375191,-42.253235 -8.057411,-64.271973c2.210022,-20.349182 7.372784,-39.690674 15.861763,-57.59668c8.502769,-18.106018 18.941837,-35.073425 31.503925,-50.688416c12.562096,-15.61499 25.428627,-29.801971 38.585793,-42.360931c13.343895,-12.345093 30.760139,-28.228119 52.635963,-47.421387z" id="path9" stroke-width="0.602291" stroke="#131516" fill-rule="evenodd" style=""/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="5760" y2="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="120" x2="5760" y2="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="160" x2="5760" y2="160" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="5760" y2="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="240" x2="5760" y2="240" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"></line>

  <use href="#gclef" x="20" y="0" width="100"/>

</svg>
```